# Visual Studio Emulator for Android couldn’t determine the host IP address

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever I'm trying to debug and run the application using Android Emulator from visual studio 2015 getting some below error. So help me on this, I'm very tried from this error.

The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system:

Couldn't auto-detect the guest system IP address.

Some functionality might be disabled.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xamarin, try reinstalling the emulator in the worst case.

Comment: See the troubleshooting guides: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_2 / https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: Thanks for quick reply i  used the both step 1. I tried to Troubleshooting but got same problem then 2. I re-installed the emulator but getting same problem

Answer (score 17):

Two things need to be checked:

1. VS2015 installed components.

[image]

2. More importantly make sure that vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch) is enabled in Network Connections.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To fix this I:

- opened Hyper-V Manager
- Went to Virtual Switch Manager on the Right hand pane
- Deleted all Virtual Switches
- Then opened Visual Studio Emulator
- Deleted all Android Emulators
- Uninstalled / Reinstalled Android Emulator for Visual Studio
- Openened Reinstalled Visual Studio Emulator
- Downloaded an Emulator and Ran and it worked again

Comment: How to open __Hyper-V Manager__?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: There are [serveral ways](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/open-install-hyper-v-manager/).